# how can i start a video from a specific second in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, video, flvplayback

i have a problem about action script 3.  i have a flv video and its totaltime is 6 seconds. i want to start it from 2. seconds with seekSeconds(). if i write bigger than 6 values in seekSeconds it will only play the video from head to end.İf i write smaller than 6 ,it won't work.what can i write in seekSeconds() to start the video from 2 seconds?

```
function useParams()
{
var obj:Object = new Object();

var j;
for (j in this.myParams)
{
    if (j == "url")
    {
        src = this.myParams[j];
    }
    else if (j=="bas")
    {
        startTime = int(this.myParams[j]);
    }
    else
    {
        stopTime = int(this.myParams[j]);
    }

    txt.text +=  j + "  -  " + this.myParams[j];
}
//fk.source = src;
txt.text = String(startTime);

}

fk.addEventListener(VideoEvent.READY, bitti);
function bitti(eventObject:VideoEvent):void
{ 
//fk.play();
trace(fk.totalTime);
fk.seek(2);
trace(fk.playheadTime);
//trace(fk.playheadTime);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for [VideoPlayer](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/video/VideoPlayer.html#event:ready), Event.READY is dispatched:

> Event dispatched when an FLV file is loaded and ready to display. It starts the first time you enter a responsive state after you load a new FLV file with the play() or load() method. It starts only once for each FLV file that is loaded.

It is possible the video is ready but it hasn't buffered to an adequate amount for seeking. You can change the [bufferTime](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/fl/video/VideoPlayer.html#bufferTime) to a value greater than 2 although I am not certain that will guarantee Event.READY will get fired at the time you need. Also note the property of seek for progressive downloads:

> For a progressive download, you can seek only to a keyframe; therefore, a seek takes you to the time of the first keyframe after the specified time.

So make sure you set a bufferTime that is adequately advanced passed 2 seconds to ensure you are passed a keyframe.

**Note:** there is a bufferTime on both a VideoPlayer and the NetStream so you may have to adjust one or the other or both.

Comment: thanks and i have another question.  I use seekSeconds() to start a video from a specific time.But when i write seekSeconds(1),seekSeconds(2),seekSeconds(3),seekSeconds(4) and seekSeconds(5) the video starts from fifth seconds.when i write seekSeconds() from fifth seconds to fifteenth seconds the video starts fifteenth seconds.How i can solve this problem .thanks for any help